# Can I make a sheet private in a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets with multiple sheets. The first sheet pulls data from all the other sheets. I need to share the first sheet with all users but I only want to share the rest of the sheets to certain individuals (so not all users of the Sheets can view them, but all users will have to be able to edit their individual page).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the correct answer is that you need to create separate spreadsheet files, with individual privacy settings for each, and one of them pulling data from the other sheets.

(it's unfortunate that Google calls the files "Google Sheets" and that worksheets within them are also called sheets.   [Very confusing](http://googlespreadsheets-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/understanding-google-sheets-spreadsheets-and-worksheets.html).)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other submissions, using the *Named and Protected Ranges* option, you can adjust permissions for each sheet. Add a protected range for each sheet, and within each sheet, adjust permissions to suit your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it.
For doing this you need to mark the Private option when you create the sheet which you want to create for you.

Comment: Do you know where this private option is? I can protect each individual sheet but that just means other users can't edit the sheet but they can still see it. I need to stop other users from seeing the sheet

Answer (score -4):

I'm trying to do the same thing. I fear the answer is you can't.
For me, this really limits the usefulness of Google Sheets.
It seems every time I try to do something I get the same answer.
You can't.

Comment: This doesn't add anything not already written in another answer. If you agree with another answer, up-vote it (when you have the privileges to do so).